# For spring cloud gateway dynamic route, one route is wrong and all routes will be wrong

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

For spring cloud gateway dynamic route, if one route is wrong, all routes cannot be routed. How to deal with it?
Because we won't restart the gateway service after reconfiguring a route, this issue may affect all routes.
For example:
My route configuration is like this.

```
gateway:
  routes:
    - id: test_route
      predicates:
        - Path=/httpbin/**
        - Header=,
      uri: http://127.0.0.1:8031
      filters:
        - RewritePath=/httpbin/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

and the exception:

```
Field error in object 'Header' on field 'header': rejected value [null];
```

Comment: Here are some ideas for this issue [#600](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/600)